# MySQLdb security when connecting to a remote server?

Tags: python, security, mysql-python

```
    db = MySQLdb.connect(host ="host",
        user="user",
        passwd="pass",
        db="dbname")
    q = db.cursor()
```

So, that's my code block, I was just wondering, how easy would this be to reverse engineer, and does mysqldb send authentications over cleartext?

I am creating a program that connects to  a mySQL server over the internet, would someone be able to get my credentials?

Would someone be able to get my server login details?

Comment: You can read this section in MySQL docs, which states the authentication mechanism it uses: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/connection-phase.html#packet-Protocol::AuthSwitchRequest . Normally, web server is communicating with MySQL server back-to-back ( calling local MySQL server, or a MySQL server located in private network ), so security should not be a concern, assuming the network sector of your server is secured .

Comment: It connects to a remote mysql server...
There is no websever, it's a standalone SQL server.

Comment: okay, I *think* I have a workaround, this application only uses the SELECT statement, I'm just going to set up permissions on the SQL server, so the user connecting can only run SELECT, making it so the data cannot be edited.

Comment: re-think about your network architecture. remote database server adds too much overheads on traffic, therefore brings penalty on response time. Not suggested to use remote database server if you want responsive program .

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL server could be configured to use SSL to secure the connection.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287088/ca-ssl-parameter-for-python-mysqldb-not-working-but-key-does) for an example of using MySQLdb with an SSL connection and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/configuring-for-ssl.html) for some info on configuring the server.

Answer (score 1):

In your example above the username, password and all other data would be sent in cleartext.

Here are two related questions [Python MySQLDB SSL Connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173650/python-mysqldb-ssl-connection) , [CA SSL parameter for Python MySQLdb not working, but key does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287088/ca-ssl-parameter-for-python-mysqldb-not-working-but-key-does)

If you have access to change configure the MySQL server, we can help configure SSL.

MySQL supports encrypted connections.  The MySQL server you are connecting to must be configured to use SSL and the client must add an SSL parameter when connecting.

[Using SSL connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-ssl-connections.html)

```
shell> mysql --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem ...
```

You can test if the server you are connecting to supports SSL my adding `--ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem`.
ca-cert.pem: Use this as the argument to [--ssl-ca](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ssl-options.html#option_general_ssl-ca) on the server and client sides. (The CA certificate, if used, must be the same on both sides.)

[MySQL SSL Example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-certs.html) describes the process from setting up MySQL for and connecting with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Passwords shouldn't be hardcoded in the code. Python has the convention of a config.py module, where you can keep such values separate from the rest of your code.

Please have a look here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-python-coding.html

The question regarding SSL to prevent disclosure has been answered above.

Fabio
@fcerullo